# Add new field related with other (this field isentity reference) - Custom entity

Tags: entities

Is it possible to add a new field related to the entity reference field?

Let me explain, I have one field called "student_id" which is an entity reference type, so I need to assign one status for it. Is this possible? Can you support me?

Comment: The entity reference always points to an entity.  So if the entity reference is pointing to an entity of type **Student ID**, you can add an additional field **Status** to the entity type  **Student ID**.  If you need to add a field to a "relationship" between two entities, you can do it with the Relation module (https://www.drupal.org/project/relation) in Drupal 7, but no such solution exists for Drupal 8/9.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for Fields to have Fields, although these types of structures are usually constructed through Paragraphs in D8.

Paragraphs are basically 2-level entity reference fields. First you create the Paragraph for the Student ID, then inside the Paragraph create two fields, one for the ID number or other info, another for the Status.

There are other ways of achieving similar results but generally speaking this might be the common way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the custom entity in code? Then try this code for a custom field type:

```
/**
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "entity_reference_quantity",
 *   label = @Translation("Entity reference quantity"),
 *   description = @Translation("An entity field containing an entity reference with a quantity."),
 *   category = @Translation("Reference"),
 *   default_widget = "entity_reference_autocomplete",
 *   default_formatter = "entity_reference_label",
 *   list_class = "\Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList",
 * )
 */

class EntityReferenceQuantity extends EntityReferenceItem {

  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface 
  $field_definition) {
    $properties = parent::propertyDefinitions($field_definition);
    $quantity_definition = DataDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(new TranslatableMarkup('Quantity'))
      ->setRequired(TRUE);
    $properties['quantity'] = $quantity_definition;
    return $properties;
  }

}
```

You need a custom widget and formater as well. See this blog post for the entire code which is also the source for the code I've posted https://www.lullabot.com/articles/extending-a-field-type-in-drupal-8